# Access: Set Property Macro does not work in vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

The following works fine as a macro, in the `On Activate` Event, but not in vba.

[image: Macro Snip Image]

Is there something wrong with my `If` statement? I have tried `.Value` and `.Text`, with the same result - the `If` statement, will not resolve - no matter where I put it; `Activate`, `Load`, `Open`, `Current`...

```
Option Compare Database
Private Sub Report_Activate()
    If Me.textBox = "SomeText25" Then
        Me.SomeLabel.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

This works alone...

```
Me.SomeLabel.Visible = False
```

DoCmd doesn't work at all, no matter how I write it.

`DoCmd.SetProperty`

Comment: Does `If [textBox] = "SomeText25" Then` work? Is the control actually named `textBox`? Because that *might* confuse the heck out of VBA, if not of whoever ends up maintaining that code. `TextBox` is a *type* identifier. It might work, but you're shadowing the type name in the report's scope.

Comment: The names have been changed - the Macro If/Then works without issue.

Comment: That wasn't the question. Does `If [textBox] = "SomeText25" Then` work *in the VBA code*.

Comment: Your question was verbatim, what I wrote, in the macro, but No - it doesn't work in VBA, no matter how I write it... alone in brackets, Me dot, Me exclamation point, quotes, nada...

Comment: My guess is, it has something to do with the order of operations, in vba vs, embedded macros.

Comment: I cannot recreate your issue. In the same `OnActivate` event with same VBA coding logic (different control names), code renders fine without errors, Why are you treating a report like a form? Are you hoping to enter textbox on a report? Please set up a reproducible example.

Comment: I have a group of controls, on a report, that are missing values, for some of the query results. For auditing purposes, blank fields cannot be present, on the printed reports - so I hide them, until we can get the data, for that specific usage updated.

Comment: The attached image, is a screen snip, of the actual working macro - I just typed in the control names and value - the quotes and brackets, were not altered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parenthesis apparently does the trick in vba...

`If (textBox = "SomeText25") Then`

At which point, both `DoCmd.SetProperty` and `Me.ControlName`, work equally as well.